# app crashes while trying to send image Android

Tags: android

I have a problem while trying to send an image from my app to the server. I know where it crashes.
These are my files:

RestClient.java

```
package edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo;

import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;


public class RestClient {

private static final int DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30000;
private static final int DEFAULT_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT = 60000;
//private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
private static final String JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
private static final String UTF8 = "UTF8";
private static final String DEBUG = RestClient.class.getName();


public Result put(String url, String json) {
    return executeRequest(new HttpPut(url), json, DEFAULT_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);
}



private Result executeRequest(HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase request, String json, int timeout) {
    request.addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, JSON_CONTENT_TYPE);
    try {
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json,UTF8));
    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG, e.getMessage());
        return Result.error();
    }
    return executeRequest(request,timeout);
}


private Result executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, int timeout) {

    int responseCode = -1;
    String responseContent = null;
    //request.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, encodeCredentials(userCredentials));
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(entity!=null) {
            responseContent = EntityUtils.toString(entity, UTF8);
        }

    }catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG, e.getMessage());
        return Result.error();
    }
    return new Result(responseCode, responseContent);
}


}
```

ImageDTO.java:

```
public class ImageDTO {

public String id;
public String image;

public ImageDTO(String id, String image) {
    this.id = id;
    this.image=image;
}
```

}

Result.java:

```
package edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo;

public class Result {

public static final int COMMUNICATION_ERROR = -1;
public static final int OK_SUCCESS = 200;
public static final int BAD_REQUEST = 400;
public static final int UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
public static final int NOT_FOUND = 404;
public static final int INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = 500;

private int responseCode;
private String resultContent;

public Result(int responseCode, String resultContent) {
    this.responseCode = responseCode;
    this.resultContent = resultContent;
}

public int getResponseCode() {
    return this.responseCode;
}

public String getResultContent() {
    return this.resultContent;
}

public static Result error() {
    return new Result(COMMUNICATION_ERROR, "ERROR");
}

}
```

And the code in my activity related to this:

```
String strBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            int id = 1;

            ImageDTO imdto = new ImageDTO(Integer.toString(id), strBase64);

            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            String jsonDTO = new Gson().toJson(imdto);

            Log.i("Pablo", jsonDTO);
            Result result = client.put(SERVICE_URL, jsonDTO);
            if (result.getResponseCode() != 200) Log.i("****************", "Oups! Smth went wrong!!!");
            else Log.i("****************", "Response = 200 , Connection Established :D");
```

My app fails in RestClient.java in this line:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I don't know why it fails because the RestClient and Result files works fine in other project.

Also I have to say that Base64 code is not complete displayed in IntelliJ Idea. If I ask about the latest char, it is the correct one but it cannot display all of them in log mode.

This is the log showing the fail:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo, PID: 27028
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} to activity {edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo/edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo.MyCameraActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    at edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo.RestClient.executeRequest(RestClient.java:61)
    at edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo.RestClient.executeRequest(RestClient.java:46)
    at edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo.RestClient.put(RestClient.java:33)
    at edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo.MyCameraActivity.onActivityResult(MyCameraActivity.java:78)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Added, I think this is what you mean

Comment: USe AsyncTask to send your image to server.

Comment: I want to use that in my final app but now I am trying to send just for knowing how to do it. Is the problem related to that?

Comment: It solved the problem. I just tried now. Thanks. Now I have to check why it doesn't write anything on server side but I guess that problem comes from php.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One more question, in your code example you use the package `edu.gvsu.cis.masl.camerademo`, I tried to do the same, but in my case IDE doesn't recognize it. Hence, how can I add this package to SDK/IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

**Reason :**
The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

Refer [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) for more information.

**Problem :**
You are doing a network related task/operation in `Main thread (UI thread)`.

**Solution:**
It should be done in a `worker thread` .
You can use `AsyncTask` provided by android in this situation.
Perform all the network related task in `doInbackground` method of `AsyncTask`.

**Note :**
You can also make use of `StrictMode`.

`StrictMode` is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them.

`StrictMode` is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread, where UI operations are received and animations take place. Keeping disk and network operations off the main thread makes for much smoother, more responsive applications. By keeping your application's main thread responsive, you also prevent `ANR dialogs` from being shown to users.

Refer [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) for more information.